# Chrome on Android is sending a request on every keystroke to my site

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome

When I use the address bar in Google Chrome (on **Android** -- but *not* Windows) to access my site (ASP.NET MVC 4, Razor) the browser is sending a request for every keystroke in the address bar.

The result is a bunch of 404 errors in my application log -- one for each keystroke until a 'defined-route' name has been fully typed-in.

#### Example

To clarify: If I am sitting at the home page for my site with the address bar reading:

`http://test.mysite.com/`

and then attempt to navigate to a defined route `TEST` by typing those four-characters at the end of the value currently in the address bar, then I get a request for each character and a 404 for the keystroke of each of the first three characters:

```
NOT FOUND: (404) http://test.mysite.com/T
NOT FOUND: (404) http://test.mysite.com/TE
NOT FOUND: (404) http://test.mysite.com/TES
```

I understand that the search engines do this type of thing for nifty tricks with optimizing requests but why would the browser be doing this sort of thing for my site?

Is this normal?